# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server selected improper ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA

Tags: classnotfoundexception, japplet, sslexception

When applet is served through HTTPS connection I am getting following exception.

This problem is experienced at Java 1.7.0_25 but not at java 1.6.

when i look at the chipersuit supported by java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#PLUG) i see SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA in list.

Is there any one experiencing this error? and What should i do to deal with this error?

```
Java Plug-in 10.25.2.15
Using JRE version 1.7.0_25-b15 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
User home directory = /home/mithat
----------------------------------------------------
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://mytest.domain.tr/LoginWeb/myapplet.jar,     version: null]
network: Connecting https://mytest.domain.tr/LoginWeb/myapplet.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://mytest.domain.tr:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server selected improper ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
   at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:266)
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(ClientHandshaker.java:464)
   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:143)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
   at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.connect(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:205)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:71)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:88)
   at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://mytest.domain.tr/LoginWeb/myapplet.jar, version: null]
...
network: Cache entry not found [url:   https://mytest.domain.tr/LoginWeb/test/AppletTest.class, version: null]
network: Connecting https://mytest.domain.tr/LoginWeb/test/AppletTest.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://mytest.domain.tr:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.AppletTest
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
   ...
security: Reset deny session certificate store
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
```

Comment: We are using SSL accelerator module on Cisco network device to establish SSL connection. After then this network device talks to web server(Ibm Http Server) by using HTTP protocol to process request. If I configure HTTP server to serve through https and remove cisco device  the error doesn't occur at java 1.7. I'm confused does the problem caused by java or cisco?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue could be related to reverse proxy setup. For example in apache you have to set below parameters.

```
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

You can find similar option for other reverse proxy servers.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think the problem is not related proxy settings because mod_proxy is not enabled on http server. Actually http server don't know where request comes from client or cisco ssl module. It just knows that it speaks HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

We examined the network by means of Wireshark and we found out the server chooses mentioned chipher suite which is actually not in client-hello and disabled at Java8. After change SSL module of network device problem is resolved. You can find default supported chipher suites in java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html).